# Cacti/rrdtool error -> Poller[0] ERROR: SQL Row Failed!, Error:'1033'

Tags: linux, networking, mysql, php, cacti

I have cacti working flawlessly on a centos 7.0 machine but I need it working on a centos 6.3 machine.
I download the same version of cacti as what is on the 7.0 and I installed rrdtool from yum.
After performing a successful base installation of cacti and confirm it works. 
I then copy over the database rsync /var/mysql/mydb and restart mysqld 
I see my data but ‘none of the charts appear’ and I get this error in my cacti.log

```
10/01/2014 04:12:31 AM - CMDPHP: Poller[0] ERROR: SQL Row Failed!, Error:'1033', SQL:"select  host.id,  host.hostname,  host.snmp_community,  host.snmp_version,  host.snmp_username,  host.snmp_password,  host.snmp_auth_protocol,  host.snmp_priv_passphrase,  host.snmp_priv_protocol,  host.snmp_context,  host.snmp_port,  host.snmp_timeout,  host.disabled  from host  where host.id=1"
```

since, I have upgraded MySQL to 5.4 and rddtool  to 1.4.8 and tried a different cacti versions also.
I have also tried every script in cli/ to repair the DB or bring it up to specs.
Mysqlcheck say the database is just fine.
Same error

How do I get my cacti charts to work?

Comment: [Error 1033](http://vancelucas.com/blog/mysql-error-1033-incorrect-information-in-file/)

Comment: @eyoung100 my database engine is MyISAM http://paste.ee/p/vzWHt , I have already tried to delete both the ib_logfile* files and nothing 'tmp' exist in my.cnf, though permissions are correct for /tmp  (system default)

Comment: Well Googling Error 1033 only brings up InnoDB.  I looked High and Low about 3 pages deep.

Comment: @eyoung100 on a hunch I started to convert each table to InnoDB, one by one because scripting failed and I got a very interesting error  ->  https://bpaste.net/show/f4f793883498  ERROR 1033 (HY000): Incorrect information in file: './cacti3/host.frm'

Comment: That past confirms all the errors I found on Google

Answer (score 0):

the tables plugin_flowview_schedules and host were corrupt and mysqlcheck was not detecting this. found while converting each table one by one to InnoDB and got the 1033 error.
I did a mysql export of just the tables and then imported the .sql into the CentOS 6 machine and the error went away and the graphs popped right up.
Note that I rsync'ed the /var/lib/mysql/* migration and probably should of done a traditional mysql export and would of saved myself the headaches.